# Streamline Date Parsing into method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to think of a cleaner way to do this.  I want to move this into a helper method but I do not like using out params.  I realize I have to use out params for the TryParse, I don't have a choice but I'd like to get this into some kind of reusable method:

startDate and endDate are in "yyyy/mm/dd" format and are string to begin with and I'm parsing below.

```
DateTime startDt;
DateTime endDt;
startDt = (DateTime.TryParse(startDate, out startDt) ? startDt : DateTime.Now);
endDt = ((!DateTime.TryParse(endDate, out endDt) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate))) ? (startDt.AddMinutes(Configuration.Instance.RecentOrdersWindowDurationMinutes)) : endDt;
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I suggest you use `TryParseExact` to be safe.

Comment: I want this into a method, clean code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want two results from a single method you have to either use `out` parameters or some wrapping type. If you're lazy and only doing this once, you could just use `Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>`.

```
public Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> GetRange(string startDate, string endDate)
{
    DateTime startDt;
    DateTime endDt;

    if (!DateTime.TryParse(startDate, out startDt))
        startDate = DateTime.Now;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate) || !DateTime.TryParse(endDate, out endDt))
        endDt = startDt.AddMinutes(Configuration.Instance.RecentOrdersWindowDurationMinutes);

    return new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(startDt, endDt);
}
```

If you're looking for the more generalized case, dealing with just one at a time, you could write a `TryParse` that accepts a default value.

```
public DateTime TryParseOrDefault(string str, DateTime def)
{
    DateTime ret;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out ret))
        return ret;
    else
        return def;
{
```

**Edit:**

In re to a comment, your concrete type would just look something like this:

```
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could use that instead of the `Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>`.

Comment: that Tuple is looking slick, I might try that.  Thanks

Comment: in your tuple method I assume you're using a custom TryParse rather than the one built into the framework which requires an out param?

Comment: sure wish there was a way to name the items in a tuplet such as "startDate" and "endDate" rather than "Item1" and"Item2"

Comment: That's what concrete types *do*... Just make a type with two properties for those.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your own `TryParse` helper method, but instead of returning `bool` and setting the actual `DateTime` value using `out` parameter, you can return `DateTime?`, which will let you set default value quite nicely using `??` operator:

```
public static class DateTimeUtils
{ 
    public static DateTime? TryParse(string value)
    {
        DateTime result;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(value, out result))
            return null;
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
var myString = "01/01/2015";
var myDateTime = DateTimeUtils.TryParse(myString) ?? DateTime.Now;
```

This way you don't have to declare `myDateTime` before calling `TryParse`, like you'd have to do with standard `DateTime.TryParse` method.

In your case it would be something like:

```
DateTime startDt = DateTimeUtils.TryParse(startDate) ?? DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDt = DateTimeUtils.TryParse(endDate) ?? startDt.AddMinutes(Configuration.Instance.RecentOrdersWindowDurationMinutes);
```